# Generate random weights numbers with limited sum

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a random list of 8 integers between [0, 4] with weights and the sum should be 12.

Something like this:

```
from random import choices

while True:
    lst = choices(population=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], weights=[0.20, 0.30, 0.30, 0.15, 0.05], k=8)
    if sum(lst) == 12:
        print(lst)
        break
```

There is a smarter way to do that?

Comment: @dfundako Which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Severin's solution is simple and should to be quick for a large part of the parameter space, but might get slow out at the edges of the distribution.  For example, generating 30 values that have to sum to 100 will probably take a few seconds until it randomly stumbles on a valid solution

The following code makes sure it only samples from values that are valid, so has a more deterministic runtime:

```
def sample_values(population, k, total, *, weights=None):
    if weights is None:
        # weights not probabilities, so no need to sum to 1
        weights = [1] * len(population)
    
    # ensure population is a sorted list, with weights in consistant order
    population, weights = zip(*sorted(zip(population, weights)))
    population = list(population)
    weights = list(weights)
    
    result = []
    for _ in range(k):
        # population values that would take us past the running total should be excluded
        while population[-1] > total:
            del population[-1]
            del weights[-1]
        
        # maintain k as the number of remaining items
        k -= 1
        
        # remove anything where just using it and then maximal values wouldn't get us to the total
        remain_lim = total - max(population) * k
        while population[0] < remain_lim:
            del population[0]
            del weights[0]
        
        # sample next value
        n, = choices(population, weights)
        result.append(n)
        
        # maintain total as the remaining total
        total -= n
    
    return result
```

The first call to `tee` really wants [`strict=True` from Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/), but have left that out as I presume you're not using that yet

The above can, e.g., be used as:

```
sample_values(range(5), 8, 12, weights=[0.20, 0.30, 0.30, 0.15, 0.05])
```

and runs in ~12µs which is comparable to Severin's `multinomial` solution which takes ~18µs for these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could sample from [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) which automatically gets the right sum, and reject out-of-range values

Along the lines, Python 3.9.1, Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def smpl(rng):

    while True:

        q = rng.multinomial(12, [1./8.]*8)

        if np.any(q > 4):
            continue
        return q
```